# Generating many icons for the same Flutter app (dynamically)

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-launcher, app-launcher

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYh9b.jpg)I need to generate more than one app launcher icon using Flutter, but the generation will be based on users' behavior so I cannot make it static, every icon will start a different use case, as shown in the image below, one starts google sports news and the other starts weather news
[this 2 icons starts 2 different routes but both are related to the same app (https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Cq0.jpg)

I tried to use flutter_launcher_icon but i think it does not help